# About workflow input section in DRAGEN-GATK v1 whole genome analysis script

Tags: wgs, gatk

I am trying to understand the WDL script for the DRAGEN-GATK whole genome analysis and I am faced with this input section inside the workflow definition which I really don't get:

```
# WORKFLOW DEFINITION
workflow WholeGenomeGermlineSingleSample {

  String pipeline_version = "3.0.0"

      input {
        SampleAndUnmappedBams sample_and_unmapped_bams
        DNASeqSingleSampleReferences references
        DragmapReference? dragmap_reference
        VariantCallingScatterSettings scatter_settings
        PapiSettings papi_settings
    
        File? fingerprint_genotypes_file
        File? fingerprint_genotypes_index
    
        File wgs_coverage_interval_list
    
        Boolean provide_bam_output = false
        Boolean use_gatk3_haplotype_caller = true
    
        Boolean dragen_functional_equivalence_mode = false
        Boolean dragen_maximum_quality_mode = false
    
        Boolean run_dragen_mode_variant_calling = false
        Boolean use_spanning_event_genotyping = true
        Boolean unmap_contaminant_reads = true
        Boolean perform_bqsr = true
        Boolean use_bwa_mem = true
        Boolean allow_empty_ref_alt = false
        Boolean use_dragen_hard_filtering = false
      }
```

What do the first 5 lines under `input` mean? Are they Strings? Files? Or what exactly?

Thanks in advance for your help

Nawar

---

**GATK** is Broad's VCF
**DRAGEN** is Dynamic Read Analysis for GENomics to facilitates hardware-acceleration of analytics and processes including conversion, compression, mapping, alignment, sorting, duplicate marking, haplotype variant calling and joint genotyping.

https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360045944831-DRAGEN-GATK